# java.sql.SQLException: Unrecognized SQL type -102 while connecting to Oracle Database from Apache Spark

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm trying to load a remote Oracle Database table on to Apache Spark shell.

This is how I started the spark-shell.

```
./spark-shell --driver-class-path ../jars/ojdbc6.jar --jars ../jars/ojdbc6.jar --master local
```

And I get a Scala prompt, where I try to load an Oracle database table like below. (I use a custom JDBC URL)

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=WHATEVER)(HOST=myDummyHost.com)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dummy)(INSTANCE_NAME=dummyKaMummy)(UR=A)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))").option("dbtable", "THE_DUMMY_TABLE").option("user", "DUMMY_USER").option("password", "DUMMYPASSWORD").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load()
```

(Replaced employer data with dummy variables)

And then I get this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unrecognized SQL type -102
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:246)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  ... 49 elided
```

I tried to see if there is an issue with the quotes, but it's not that.

Can somebody save my life, please?

Comment: Consider trying a newer Oracle JDBC driver. ojdbc6 means it was written for Java 6, so it is pretty old.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel From this `https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html`, ojdbc6 is for Oracle 11g and that's what we use.

Comment: Also from Oracle JDBC FAQ, under section `What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?`,  **ojdbc6.jar is supported with JDK6, JDK7 and JDK8.**
`https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html`

Comment: Yes, it may work, that doesn't necessarily mean it is the best option. Newer drivers also support Oracle 11... and newer drivers support newer JDBC features which tools may rely on. In any case, it was just a suggestion for you to try.

Comment: You might want to acquaint yourself with the [Law of Demeter](https://hackernoon.com/object-oriented-tricks-2-law-of-demeter-4ecc9becad85)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just have tried with ojdbc7, ojdbc8, ojdbc10 and they fail with the same error. Ojdbc14 jar throws a different error as mentioned here. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100117/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception`

Comment: ojdbc14 is for Java 1.4 and is even older than ojdbc6. If it also gives an error with the newer drivers, this could mean that  the problem is with a non-standard Oracle datatype that Spark doesn't support (type code -102 is not defined in the JDBC standard).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you are right. I just created a really simple table and tried loading it, it loads fine. But I'm not sure which type from the remote table that Spark can't support. The only odd man I could see is TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE.

Comment: Try creating a table with half the columns of the problematic tables, if the error doesn't occur, try creating one with the other half. Continue doing this until you have identified the column (or columns) that is the problem, then consider updating your question with a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I figured the problem is the TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an incompatible field in the database. If you cannot modify the database, but would still like to read it, the solution would be to ignore specific columns (in my case it's a field with type `geography`). With the help of [How to select specific columns through Spack JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843525/how-to-select-specific-columns-through-spack-jdbc), here's a solution in **pyspark** (scala solution would be similar):

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=connectionString, table="(select colName from Table) as CompatibleTable", properties=properties)
```

Comment: we can also use TO_CHAR() to convert the timestamp with local time zone column  to string in the above sql query.